# How to filter lines containing 4 words?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a column with lines containing "/" and others that have 4 words separated by several spaces and some other lines. I'm interested in filter out
those that contains `/` and those that have 4 words separated by spaces. I know how to match the lines containing `/` but I don't know how to identify
the lines that contains the 4 words.

```
The / house
is / white
The   car  is       blue
Xyz 
plane   is     white
My    Bike   is   green
abc
```

My current code is like this. I've added a conditional column that writes "True" if line contains "/" and otherwise writes "False"

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "/") then True else False)
in
    #"Added Conditional Column"
```

How to do this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want to include or exclude the lines with `/` or the lines with 4 words, but there is no need for a conditional column. Just use one of the two `filter` lines to get what you want

***Data***
[image]

***Include***

```
    filter = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", 
        each Text.Contains([Strings],"/") or List.Count(List.Select(Text.Split([Strings]," "),(li)=>li <> ""))=4)
```

[image]

***Exclude***

```
   filter = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", 
        each not Text.Contains([Strings],"/") and List.Count(List.Select(Text.Split([Strings]," "),(li)=>li <> ""))<>4),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Ron. It works so fine!. Both solutions helped me to learn even I need this time the "Include" version. May you give me a tip in how to debug this M Code? for example like "Evaluate Formula" in Excel or F8 in VBA. Something like that. I hace issues to understand code with nested functions like your solution. Thanks again

Comment: @RasecMalkic You can select the particular Applied Step and then make changes (either in the Advanced Code editor, or in the formula bar), and observe the results at that step. There is no `Formula Evaluate` tool in PQ. There are many online blogs and courses though. Start with the basics and learn about Lists, Records and Tables.

Comment: Than you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "/") then true else false)
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Custom1", each List.Count(List.Select(Text.Split(Text.Trim([Column1]), " "), each _ <> "")))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

The Power Query formula will help you identify the lines that contain the 4 words.
[image]